# Pivot point won't move

Tags: bezier-curves, origin

I've done this before fine but I had scaling issues so I restarted my project. I created a bezier circle and moved the points around in edit mode to what I wanted. I set the 3D cursor to one of the points in edit mode that I wanted to be the origin. I went in to object mode selected the circle and then I used set origin to the 3D cursor in the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> menu and it does not move.

It isn't a visual bug as the object rotates around the origin in its original place. Is there anything I've missed?

Comment: Can you show a picture of the situation?

Comment: The shift-s menu doesn't have an option to set the objects origin to the cursor. That's accessed from the Object > Set Origin menu.

Answer (score 0):

As John Eason, set origin is not available in the <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> pop-up menu, you need to go in *Object* mode and right click > *Set Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor*.

Or enable the *Transform Affects Only > Origins* option and in that case you can use the <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Selection to 3D Cursor* as in that case it will move the origin:

[image]

Comment: Apologies I mistakenly wrote shift s menu.

Comment: The workflow I'm following is.

Edit mode for the bezier curve and select a point.
shift+s and select cursor to selected.
Object mode right click while bezier curve selected and set_origin > origin_to_3d_cursor

Origin point doesn't move.

I did set the options to transform affects only origins

Comment: what you describe should work, maybe show some pictures or a video clip. Note that the solution withAffect Only Origins is another solution as explained

Comment: Just deleted all my work and tried it again and it worked fine. I must've carried out an action on my first curve that now prevents the origin from moving. Wish I knew what it was to avoid redoing work in the future.

Comment: ok, that was weird  ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you have scaled something on one axis to 0, then the set origin to cursor won't work. Apply scale to fix this.